# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Как правильно разобрать первое предложение?

***-Можно?***

*-Войдите.*

Answer (score 4):

Можно? - Односоставное, безличное, неполное предложение. Вполне характерное для разговорной речи.

Ссылки? Например,[здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-028.htm)
И [здесь](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/442)

Comment: В предложении должен быть понятен смысл без ближайшего контекста. Что сообщается в вашем ОБН предложении? Если можно, напишите ваши пояснения или дайте ссылку на источник, где разбираются подобные разговорные отрывочные фрагменты, буду премного благодарен! Голым утверждением здесь трудно удовольствоваться...

Comment: Набираете в поисковике "неполные предложения". Подобные примеры и в вузовских учебниках, и на сайтах для ребят, и в школьных учебниках.

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается, предложению не нужна даже грамматическая основа. Все равно предложение) А если вот так :

-- ?

-- !

Здесь письменно выражены две мысли, легко восстанавливающиеся из контекста; предложения являются неполными, бессоставными, *чистоэмоциональными*)))

Виват науке, поднимаю лапы кверху! 

-- Поймал вчера щуку на 21 килограмм...

-- Да ну!!!

Comment: И что тут можно восстановить? Полный простор фантазии. Вообще